# Retrieve an instance for an email

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

Say I have the following table,  Peter and Halla,

```
Name    Age occupation  BillingContactEmail
-------------------------------------------
Peter   44  Salesman    a@a.com
Andy    43  Manager     a@a.com
Halla   33  Fisherman   b@b.com
```

How to construct a SQL to return this data set:

```
Name    Age occupation  BillingContactEmail
-------------------------------------------
Peter   44  Salesman    a@a.com
Halla   33  Fisherman   b@b.com
```

where we only retrieve an instance for an email? (meaning we will have distinct email in the end)

Comment: How did you chose Peter over Andy?

Comment: @Bohemian randomly will do

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
;with cte (rowno, Name, Age, Occupation, BillingContactEmail)
as (
    select row_number() over (partition by BillingContactEmail order by BillingContactEmail), Name, Age, Occupation, BillingContactEmail 
    from myTable
)
select Name, Age, Occupation, BillingContactEmail from cte 
where  rowno = 1
```

You may want to consider indexing your columns for better performance.

of course if you want to be specific as to who to choose, you will need to tweak the `order by` accordingly.

if the age/occupation don't matter, you can always get the names grouped by email like so:

```
select  stuff((select concat( ',', Name) from myTable a where a.BillingContactEmail = t.BillingContactEmail   for xml Path('')), 1, 1, '') as Name, 
        BillingContactEmail 
from myTable t
group by BillingContactEmail
```

output:

```
Name          BillingContactEmail 
------------- --------------------
Peter,Andy    a@a.com
Halla         b@b.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
Select distinct  email,
        (
           Select tb1.First_Name+ ','  AS [text()]
           From dbo.table1 tb1
           Where tb1.Email = 'a@a.com'
           For XML PATH ('')
        ) [Students]
From dbo.table2
WHERE Email = 'a@a.com'
```

Output:

```
Name          BillingContactEmail 
------------- --------------------
Peter,Andy,    a@a.com
```